# Creating a matrix from indices and value matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indices

I'm new to Matlab but I have trawled the documentation and cannot find an answer for what I am looking for.

I've done a number of calculations on a matrix and I have ended up with a list of indices and a list of values which should go in those indices.

for example:

```
Data =

         0         0         0         0         0         0
    3.7417    3.7417    3.7417    7.0711    3.3166    3.3166
    4.2426    4.2426    3.7417    7.0711    5.3852    7.0711
    7.0711    6.0828    5.3852    7.4833    6.0828    7.6158
    7.1414    7.4833    7.8740    8.7750    7.1414    7.8740
```

and

```
Indices =

     1     2     3     4     5     6
     3     3     1     1     6     5
     2     1     2     6     3     4
     4     5     5     2     2     2
     5     4     6     5     1     3
```

What I want to be able to do is construct a square matrix (of size n based on the largest valued index found in the indices matrix), such that the first column of `Indices` is used to index the first row of the `Result` matrix, and the values of `Data` are put in the corresponding locations of the `Result` matrix with all places not indexed with data set to 0.

I.e. with the data and indices matrices from above I want the final matrix to look like:

```
Result =
          0   4.2426    3.7417    7.0711    7.1414         0
     4.2426        0    3.7417    7.4833    6.0828         0
     3.7417   3.7417         0         0    5.3852    7.8740 
     7.0711   7.4833         0         0    8.7750    7.0711
     7.1414   6.0828    5.3852         0         0    3.3166
          0   7.6158    7.8740    7.0711    3.3166         0
```

(There may be some mistakes with the above as I did it by hand but it should provide an idea of what I'm wanting to do)

Is there a quick an easy way in Matlab to do this? Many function return the indices and I was hoping there would be an easy way to update/construct a matrix using these indices.

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way I know how to do it is by creating a sparse matrix based on your data and indices:

```
[M,N] = size(Indices); indmax = max(Indices(:));
Result = sparse(repmat(1:N,M,1),Indices,Data,indmax,indmax);
```

Hopefully someone comes along and shows us an even cleaner method.

Comment: I don't think it gets much cleaner than this.  You can always wrap `sparse` with `full` if that's the goal. +1

Comment: @chappjc I keep hoping that one of these days someone will come along and show me how to index a disjoint list of elements in a matrix without using `sub2ind`. For some reason I have always taken issue with the fact that I have to provide the size of matrix I am indexing into.

Comment: Yeah, the fact that subscripts are taken pairwise is not intuitive.  Why `Result([1 2],[1 2])` refers to 4 elements and not 2 can be hard to swallow.  If only MathWorks could recruit different brackets for "automatic sub2ind" behavior.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is accomplished like this:

```
[II,JJ]=meshgrid(1:size(Data,2),1:size(Data,1));
Result = zeros(size(Data,2));
Result(sub2ind(size(Result),II(:),Indices(:))) = Data(:);
```

Note that getting `II` through the `meshgrid` statement is equivalent to `II=repmat(1:size(Data,2),size(Data,1),1);`.

Answer (score 2):

This solution, based on `bsxfun`, seems to be a little faster that those by @nispio and @chappjc:

```
S = max(Indices(:));
Result = zeros(S);
Result(bsxfun(@plus, (Indices-1)*S, 1:S)) = Data;
```

Comment: +1 for writing your own `sub2ind` function.  :)  However, what you gain in speed you lose in readability, in my opinion.